# Cross Side Scripting (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain

I am trying to Get Data from another url using JavaScript but failed , I tried All Solution from jsfiddle and Stack-overflow but one error is not going away

http://renault.twobulls.com/?code=waeuhh (Destination URL)

I tried `$.getJson,$.ajax`, and all even jsonp too...please help me out, I have this error when I use call back in url for jsonp

Error:
[image: error]

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: you can hit this url and check response directly

http://renault.twobulls.com/?code=waeuhh

response 

{"code":"waeuhh","photoid":"1417564891877515"}

Comment: JSON is correct. Edit your answer and post your code. You are making a syntax error, welcome to SO btw.

Comment: i copied code from Stackoverflow and jsfiddle too

can you please write a simple code and make request from that url

renault.twobulls.com/?code=waeuhh

i am adding code that i used

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

    $("body").delegate('#submit', 'click', function ()
    {
        var url = "http://renault.twobulls.com/?code=waeuhh";
        $.getJSON(url+'&callback=?', function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseData);
        });
    });
});

@Mouser code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a JSONP request but the server is responding with JSON.

A JSONP response needs to be a JavaScript program that calls the function you specify as the callback in the URL with a single argument (which is the JSON payload).

Either change the server to make it respond with JSONP or change the JavaScript so it makes an XHR request (note that you will need to ensure the server allows a cross-origin XHR request using CORS).

Comment: You can't use your visitors' browsers to read data from third party sites without permission. That would be a security risk. Copy the data to your server instead.

Comment: but i need it from browser is there no way ? because this data is available when i use php file_get_contents

Comment: When you use `file_get_contents` **you** are making the request, not your visitor. You don't have your visitors cookies, passwords, ip address or private network. The server can do whatever auth it wants to do. The browser doesn't know if it can trust you with the data from the other site so you can't have it.

Comment: it is sure that i will not get response from that [link](http://renault.twobulls.com/?code=waeuhh) url using JavaScript ?

Comment: Has anything changed about it since the last 3 times I've said that you can't?

Comment: can you please provide me technical reason why it's not possible through JavaScript even we can publicly access this data by typing it in browser URL

Comment: @HafizAttaUrRahman — I already have in the comment starting "When you use file_get_contents"

Answer (score -1):

Just assign it to a variable.

> var someVar = {"code":"waeuhh","photoid":"1417564891877515"};

Comment: how can i assign it in variable 

i have no access to server